# Trying to shift left by EAX a variable

Tags: assembly, x86, bit-shift

How can I use the command `shl` to shift 1 by a variable?

```
mov one, 1

shl one , eax
```

Returns an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shift only shift by `cl`, unless you use [BMI2 shifts](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SARX:SHLX:SHRX.html). So for example:

```
mov edx, 1
shl edx, cl
```

Since you're shifting the value 1 to the left, there is an other applicable instruction: `bts`. `bts` can take any register as index.

```
xor edx, edx
bts edx, eax
```

Be careful when using it with a memory destination, the index won't be reduced modulo 32, so you can use it to (accidentally) set a bit quite far away from the base address.

Comment: memory-destination `bts` is usually slower than creating a mask with the xor + `bts edx, eax` you showed, then using `or [mem], edx`.  It decodes to a lot of uops exactly because of that crazy-CISC behaviour of treating the source-register as an index into a bit-string.

Answer (score 4):

The *only* way to shift by a variable amount is to put the shift count in the `CL` register (which is the low 8 bits of the 32-bit `ECX` register). This is [the only encoding available for any of the shift instructions that takes a register source operand](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html).

So you would need to do:

```
mov DWORD PTR [one], 1      ; initialize variable 'one'
mov ecx, eax                ; copy shift count from EAX into ECX
shl DWORD PTR [one], cl     ; one << cl
```

Note that only the low 8 bits of `ECX` are used here, but that's perfectly sufficient, since you can't shift a DWORD sized value by anything more than 32 bits anyway! In fact, on everything but the 8088/8086, the shift count will be masked to 5 bits anyway (i.e., modulo 32), limiting it to the range 0–31, inclusive.

Also, I should mention that while you *can* use a memory operand as the source for arithmetic instructions like shift, you probably *shouldn't* because it is slower than using a register. So, since you've got to clobber a register anyway, you could do:

```
mov  ecx, eax
mov  eax, 1
shl  eax, cl
mov  DWORD PTR [one], eax
```